# How to mathematically calculate equity

Tags: texas-hold-em, poker-theory, omaha

I am wondering how to mathematically calculate equities in equity based poker variants( holdem, omaha, Stud ect).

Comment: This is a really broad question.  You might get a good, long winded answer, but you might be better served asking about more specific examples and seeing the techniques people use to work through them.

Comment: @CoryKendall when you say specific example do you mean game i.e. holdem or hand i.e. JdQs v Ac4c

Comment: If you search the term equity you will find many examples dealing with this on the site already, amongst other terms that will likely produce useful results also.

Comment: I mean as specific as a hand.

Comment: @TobyBooth I cannot find any that show or explain how to mathematically calculate equity.

Comment: I have read several that deal finding equities exhaustively or with additional information about boards however my question was about calculating equity mathematical and only knowing your hand and your opponents hand

Comment: @idaho The deck is a fixed size.  You just run all the combinations per the card game rules.

Comment: @Frisbee yes that is a way to calculate equity however it is by exhaustive simulation I am wondering how to do it solely through mathematics.

Comment: Are you sure it can be done solely with mathematics?

Answer (score 1):

In general, equity is your expected value when you would run the same hand infinite times. In probability theory, we take the calculated chances as truth in a scenario where the event is repeated infinitely.

In poker, your equity or expected value can be calculated by taking your chance of winning and multiplying that with the value of the pot. We have in this case two scenario's:

**You currently have the best hand**

When you already have the best hand, you can only lose if your opponent(s) hit their out, which means they improve to having the best hand. Therefore, calculating equity is cumbersome since you do not know the hand of the opponent. You can however 'read' his hand based on the board, betting tells, past behaviors,  etc. When you have a solid read, say he is drawing to a flush on the flop, you know that he has a chance of 0.35 to improving and therefore you have a winning chance of 0.75 ( with for example a pair of aces.

This is, however, a very loose approximation since he may also hit two outers like two pairs or may also draw to a straight etc. In general: read the hand, approximate his outs and calculate his chance of improving. Subtract this probability from 1 and you have your probability of winning.

This probability of winning can then be multiplied with the pot, say for example $100,- and you will get your equity.

**You currently do not have the best hand**

When you do not have the best hand, you can just calculate your own chances of hitting your outs. Of course, if you are drawing to a flush but your opponent is drawing to a full house  you may have to take this into account, but that is a very hard read to do.

In [another answer](https://poker.stackexchange.com/a/6534/1597) I explain how you can calculate your probability of winning on the flop or turn. When you have this probability, you can multiply it with the pot to get your equity.

**--EDIT--** The answer where the hand of the opponent is known

To calculate the equity when you know the hand of the opponent, I am going to use the following events:

- **E1**: You hit on the turn
- **E2:** You hit on the river
- **E3:** Opponent hits on the turn
- **E4:** Opponent hits on the river

When the opponent hits, it beats your hit. Therefore, if E1 and E3 happen, you lose. If E1, E2 and E3 happen, you win, since you hit something on the river which beats the hit by your opponent.

Winning chance is in this case combining the events. The ‘-’symbol is used as a negative and hence interpreted as -event does not happen-. We can then calculate the winning change by combining the events the following way:

> E1 * -E3 * -E4 + E2 * -E4

For example, you have K♦Q♦ and your opponent has A♠A♥ with a board A♦5♦J♠

You have 7 outs to hitting a flush (not the J♦ and not counting 10♦), three to a straight (not counting 10♦) and one to royal flush, hence:

> E1 = 11/47 = 0.23

Now we can calculate the probability that you hit the flush or straight on the turn. Note that I count 10 outs since 10♦ would give you royal flush.

> E2.1 = 10/46 * (1 - -E1) = 0.17

Now we have to subtract the probability that the full house fell which makes this flush or straight obsolete:

> E2.2 = 0.17 * 0.85 = 0.14 (see below for how I get 0.85)

However, we can add the probability that the 10♦ fell, giving you royal flush:

> E2 = 0.14 + 1/47 + 1/46 * (1-1/47) = 0.14 + 0.02 + 0.02 = 0.18

He has 7 outs to improving (1 ace, 3 fives and 3 jacks). Therefore:

> –E3 = 1-7/47 = 0.85.

E4 is the event that E3 did not happen and that opponent improves. Therefore:

> E4.1 = 7/46 * (1-7/47) = 0.13

However, also the 10♦ should not have fallen on the turn and river:

> E4 = 0.13 * 0.98 * 0.98 = 0.12

Which makes -E4 of course:

> -E4 = 1-0.12 = 0.88

Filling in the numbers:

- Hitting the turn: 0.23 * 0.85 * 0.88  = 0.17
- Hitting the river: 0.18 * 0.88 = 0.16

Which gives you a winning chance of 0.33, which is quite lower than the ‘normal’ out-hitting approximation of 0.48 (12 outs * 4)

You equity will than, of course, be 0.33 * pot-size.

You can check the above scenario at an [odd calculator](http://www.pokernews.com/poker-tools/poker-odds-calculator.htm), which gives 32,93% which is rounded of course the same as 33%

Comment: You don't have to run it a infinitely.  Just the number of combinations in the deck.

Comment: @TmKVU this would work if the person with the worst hand could only improve however the person currently with the better hand can also improve.

Comment: @Frisbee No, with infinitely I mean eliminating variance in mathematical probability theory. Like when you infinitely toss a perfect coin head and tails will each fall 50% of the time.

Comment: @idaho true, but it is hard to take this into account when playing, since you can not know your opponents hand. You can, of course, have a read and act based on that read, but then you have the same situation as when you have the best hand.

Comment: @TmKVU yes this is true however it is an approximation of your equity, I am looking for a mathematical formula for the calculation of equity. Also in these situations we can assume we know the opponents hand.

Comment: @idaho ok, I will try to crunch that math :)

Comment: @idaho Took me some time, but I hope it is clear now!

Comment: @TmKVU That got complex with just 2 player and only two cards to come.  Consider 3 starting hands and 5 cards to come - you could not go through all the possible scenarios.