# Chance formula for Texas Hold'em

Tags: texas-hold-em, poker-theory, poker-strategy

Is there any general formula to calculate how many chances you have to win a particular poker hand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just outs to improve on the next card is fairly straight forward. Probability to win is much more complex.  If it is just you against a single player on the river then you can calculate.  A starting hand against 3 random hands is very complex.

I assume you mean chances (not change).

You have poker calculators but there is no formula

A straight can get beat by flush on the river that gets beat by a full house that gets beat by 4 of a kind.  It is very complex to consider all the possibilities.

To run all the combinations is just a lot of runs.  Over 4 players with today's computing power it is not even realistic.

For multiplayer they resort to statistical probability where millions of randoms hands are run.

[Poker probability (Texas hold 'em)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poker_probability_(Texas_hold_%27em))

Comment: You had right there was a mistake in my question. I've edit it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this [this calculator](http://www.pokernews.com/poker-tools/poker-odds-calculator.htm), but basically you would need to know your opponents hand in order to actually calculate the odds.

The probability you have of hitting your *outs* however, can be calculated. Take a look at my [other answer](https://poker.stackexchange.com/a/6534/1597) to learn how.

If you have a solid read you could try to include the probability of him hitting his hand after you have hit your hand. see [this answer](https://poker.stackexchange.com/a/6542/1597) for an analysis. However, this would not be very practical at the poker table.